# SimpleUploadedFile won't POST

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I want to pass a dictionary to a function using Client. It looks like that:

```
response = self.client.post(
        '/upload_image/', {'image': image, 'tags': ['orion', ]})
```

In my view, it's posting data to i have:

```
print(request.POST)
image = request.POST['image']
tags = reguest.POST['tags']
```

There is a MultiValueDictKeyError on request.POST['image'].

`print(request.POST)` shows that dictionary looks like:

```
<QueryDict: {'tags': ['orion']}>
```

image objects is:

```
image = SimpleUploadedFile(
            'kitties.png', b'kitties_in_boxes', 'image/png')
```

It's about the image object, because when I pass something else as image (For example a string) it works well.

I suppose there is another way I could test uploading images functionality, but does someone know why this doesn't works?

Comment: Check the enctype in your forms it must be enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @Quentin What can I do if there is no form? It's only test method - view method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django separates uploaded files from other submitted data. The `tags` key exits in `request.POST`, but `image` should be in `request.FILES`. From what I can see, what you're doing is the correct way to test file upload with the test client.

[More info on forms and files in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files).